# Magento2. Serialize file doest not exists in Magento 2.1.16 version

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.1.16

I just complete my **module** n I was trying to test my module on different versions my module was working perfectly on 2.2.7 and 2.3.0 versions but when I tried on 2.1.16 then it gives me the error

> Error filtering template: Class Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json does not exist

How can I solve this **error** n what is the reason behind this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SerializerInterface interface and its implementations only exist since Magento version 2.2.
>   Because of this, it is not possible to use these classes in code that has to be compatible with Magento 2.1 or 2.0.
>   In code that is compatible with earlier versions of Magento 2, constructor dependency injection can not be used to get an instance of SerializerInterface.
>   Instead, a runtime check if the SerializerInterface definition exists can made, and if it does, it can be instantiated by directly accessing the object manager using a static method. Alternatively a check against the Magento 2 version or the magento/framework composer package version would work, too.   If the interface does not exist or an earlier version of Magento 2 is being executed, the appropriate native PHP serialization function has to be called, e.g. \serialize() or \json_encode(), depending on the usercase.

First, we need to check **SerializerInterface** class exist. If exist, use object manager to create an object and use it. If not exist, use native PHP function **serialize()** or **json_encode()**. Please refer the below code for your reference.

```
 private function serialize($data)
 {
    if (class_exists(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface::class)) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $serializer = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface::class);
        return $serializer->serialize($data);
    }
    return \serialize($data);
}
```

Please refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/framework/serializer.html) for more details.

Comment: So Brother what is the solution did I need to use two different versions for 2.1.16 and another for 2.2.X or updated versions??

Comment: check my updated answer.